Iframe Won't Show Up Unless the Form is Loaded Elsewhere
So I'm currently embedding a form from GoHighLevel onto the page at <linelava.com/contact> and as you can see it will load for a brief second and then disappear until you open up one of the popups with the form embedded there (using the button at the top right that says "Get a Free Quote" or the chat button at the bottom right. When I go to inspect it, for some reason Wordpress is automatically setting the height to 0px until I one of the popups with the from embedded, then it will get set to the height I inputted (558px).
Why is the height being automatically set to 0px?
Here is the code I have put into the custom HTML block on the backend:
<iframe
  src="https://api.leadconnectorhq.com/widget/form/EY9AaBHFKfRSNmtWPw31"
  style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;border-radius:3px"
  id="inline-EY9AaBHFKfRSNmtWPw31" 
  data-layout="{'id':'INLINE'}"
  data-trigger-type="alwaysShow"
  data-trigger-value=""
  data-activation-type="alwaysActivated"
  data-activation-value=""
  data-deactivation-type="neverDeactivate"
  data-deactivation-value=""
  data-form-name="Contact Form"
  data-height="558"
  data-layout-iframe-id="inline-EY9AaBHFKfRSNmtWPw31"
  data-form-id="EY9AaBHFKfRSNmtWPw31"
  title="Contact Form"
      >
</iframe>
<script src="https://link.msgsndr.com/js/form_embed.js"></script>


Setting it to 100% makes it the height of the containing element, which I guess is 0. Try setting it to 100vh instead.

No matter if I set it to use percentage, vh, or px it just does the same procedure of flashing a couple times on page load and then disappearing, unless one of the popups containing that form is opened, then it will load.
